# How can we convert a captured IP address to a country location when importing lead info from an external form, like on Unbounce?

Tags: leads, web2lead, country-and-state

We are capturing leads from our Unbounce landing pages, that have a Salesforce integration. Unfortunately they only provide the IP and we want to record the lead's country. How can we convert IP to country within SF?

Answer (score 1):

You can download a country to IP database, such as one from iplegence, and use that to get the country for each record, or you could call a web service that provides that translation. There is nothing special in the IP address itself that tells you which country an IP belongs to.